# Python query limited to 300 results from API, how to add pagination to update pandas table

Tags: python, api, pandas, pagination

I'm using the Mailgun API to get some data on the number of emails sent with a certain event and then the message details like subject and recipient

The response is limited to 300, but i'll need thousands

I understand that I need to use pagination, but I don't know how to use it. I think it'll be something like this:

```
nextUrl = status['paging']['next']
    data = requests.get(nextUrl, auth=("api", API_KEY), params ={"limit":300})
```

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

delivered = requests.get(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/#",
        auth=("api", "key-#"),
        params={"event" : "delivered",
                "limit" : 300}) 

raw = delivered.json()
items = raw['items']

message_elements = []

for row in items:
    message = row['message']
    message_elements.append(message)

events = []

for row in items:
    event = row['event']
    events.append(event)

message_values = []

for row in message_elements:
    message_details = row['headers']

    message_values.append(message_details)

data = pd.DataFrame(message_values)

data['event'] = events
data
```

In creates this table:

[image]

Now this table is exactly what I want, but I don't want to be limited to 300 results. I'll likely need thousands and thousands

Can someone tell me how to do that using pagination?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#events) states that 'previous-url' and 'next-url' are always returned.

> ...Both next and previous page URLs are always returned, even when retrieving one of them makes no sense. There are two such cases: previous page URL for the first result page, and next page URL for the last result page; requesting these URLs always returns an empty result page. ...

So, it looks like that you have to make the call repeatedy, eg something like this. NOTE: This is pseudo code, just an idea:

```
url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/#"
last_next_url = None
while url is not last_next_url:
    delivered = requests.get(url,
    auth=("api", "key-#"),
    params={"event" : "delivered",
            "limit" : 300}) 
    ...
    # TODO: i'm not sure about HTTP response code here:
    if delivered.status >= 200 and delivered.status < 300: 
        url = raw['next_page_url']
```

Comment: So i've discovered that it should be: ---- if delivered.status_code == 200 and delivered.status_code < 300 ----  
In your code, where would you reference the next_page_url? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Actually i'm not sure. But it has to be in the json response from the initial (and repeating) requests. So it's basically the same then in your code: raw = delivered.json(); -- you could try to do the cals from python interactive shell and observe the repsonse json.